# I want to print long_name from the json data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, fetch

I am trying to fetch the long_name from the below JSON data using angular js but unable to fetch.
CODE:

```
 {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "700109",
               "short_name" : "700109",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kolkata",
               "short_name" : "Kolkata",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "West Bengal",
               "short_name" : "WB",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kolkata, West Bengal 700109, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.6902065,
                  "lng" : 88.38850289999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.6715168,
                  "lng" : 88.35748319999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.6808046,
               "lng" : 88.37577829999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.6902065,
                  "lng" : 88.38850289999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.6715168,
                  "lng" : 88.35748319999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ1-N4xFyc-DkRzfGq4MWZa1g",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I am using the following code to solve this problem but it does not show anything

CODE:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="record in records">
         {{record.long_name}}
     </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("myController",function($scope,$http){

        $http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=700109&key=AIzaSyDNK47S-6brePCvm1Hr6L7RFWAZvsngj1E")
        // $http.get("https://www.styfash.com/post/data.json")
        .then(function(result){
           $scope.records=result.data.results.address_components;

        });

    });
</script>
```

Whenever I am trying to using `$scope.records=result.data.results` and printing `{{record.address_components}}` it is working properly but whenever I am trying to use the above-mentioned code it is not showing anything on the screen.

I am new to angular js.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$scope.records=result.data.results[0].address_components;
```

Comment: Thank you, Vivek. The code is working but I have a question that why we should add results[0] even I have tried results[1] but that is not working. Can you kindly explain me the matter?

Comment: @Shushovan : Because, results is an array and we just have one element so we are accessing 0th element. Please mark it as an answer to help others in their search as well

Answer (score 0):

What you should understand is, result.data.results is an array. Therefore you should traverse through that to obtain the child records. Check the code sample below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
    
      $http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=700109&key=AIzaSyDNK47S-6brePCvm1Hr6L7RFWAZvsngj1E")
        .then(function(result){
           $scope.records=result.data.results;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <ul>
    <div ng-repeat="record in records">
         <li ng-repeat="address in record.address_components">
         {{address.long_name}}
        </li>
     </div>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

if you just need the first record, change this line in your code

```
$scope.records=result.data.results.address_components;
```

to this

```
$scope.records=result.data.results[0].address_components;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Deneth.Somehow I was not able to run the inner loop. That's why it's not working. Now it is working fine. But you said that result.data.results[0].address_components will fetch only the first record but whenever I am running the code it is showing all the long_name data. Please explain this matter. My Code is: $scope.records=result.data.results[0].address_components; in the script tag.

Comment: I meant the first "results" record.. If you need first address_coponents,
you should do something like this result.data.results[0].address_components[0]

Comment: Can you kindly explain to me why we are using results[0]? I have tried results[1] that is not working. results[0] is not clear to me. What does it do?

Comment: results[0] means the first element of the array. In your case it only returns a single element. Hence, results[1] doesn't exist. Index of an array starts with 0. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Thank you very much once again. I have checked the code once again. This time I have come to know about the meaning of results[0]. also, I have run the code to fetch only one record that is result.data.results[0].address_components[0]. It is showing only the first record that is 700109.

Comment: result.data.results[0].address_components[0] which means the first "address_components" under the first "results".

Comment: @Shushovan Just curious whether you were able to rectify the issue. Do you need more help?